# nested routes and controller different from model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a nested model

```
resources doctors do
    resource  :doctor_profile
    resource  :organization
end
```

I want to have a registration controller called "doctor_registration_controller"

Then I want the doctors to register something like this

```
match 'doctor_signup', 'to:doctor_registration#new', :as => "doctor_signup"
```

to produce this url

localhost:3000/doctor_signup

What should be in the routes file?

Answer (score 0):

You already have that in the routes file but require some changes:

```
match "/doctor_signup" => "doctor_registration#new", :as => "doctor_signup"
```

should work if you have doctor_registration controller with a new method.

Learn more about routing the guide in [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).